# Slick slider loads my css to slow

Tags: css, slider, slick.js

I'm new here so please pardon any mistakes, I have an issue with slick slider and I haven't been able to find an answer.

I have a slider in which the slides have custom `css`, it shows one slide at a time, on the first slide it works on load but when it slides to the next slide the `css` takes a second to work (FUOC), I've noticed that if I place the `css` inline in the `js` when adding the slide the `css` works better but I want to keep my `css` all in one place, what can I do?

This is how the slide with its content looks styled:
And this is the FUOC
My html:

img

text

**name**

img

text

**name**

CSS:

```
.OpinionContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.OpinionContainer > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}


#OpImg {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: pink;
}

#OpText {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.OpinionContainer').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 2500,
dots: false,
prevArrow: false,
nextArrow: false
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the slider library into your HTML? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <!--Slick CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/><!-- jQuery -->  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slick Js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

 js is being loaded before the closing body tag

Comment: Is there anyway to get the next and previos slides ready? so that on scroll they are shown correctly, on mobile i get the image on the last slide overflowing the active slide, ive tried using overflow hidden but it doesnt work